# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SSGvSPREAD.StartForm.dt.get'

Tags: c#, winforms

My goal is to test the load time of 2 third party controls. I have a startup form and 2 other forms, each with a separate control on it. My Startup form (StartForm) creates a public DateTime variable...

```
public partial class StartForm : Form
{
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }

    public StartForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dt = DateTime.Now;
        using (Spread frm = new Spread())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dt = DateTime.Now;
        using (SSG frm = new SSG())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the variable dt in the loaded form.  Here's the code I use..

```
    private void Spread_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fpSpread1.OpenExcel(Application.StartupPath + @"\ST_XPCALC_NEW.xlsm");
        MessageBox.Show("Loading time: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartForm.dt).TotalMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
    }
```

I get this error at StartForm.dt

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SSGvSPREAD.StartForm.dt.get'

I'm probably doing something stupid...any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: How much do you understand about the difference between static and non-static fields? Does the `Spread` class know anything about the instance of `StartForm` you're calling it from?

Comment: Jon has already said it, but just to help, `dt` should be static if you want to access it the way you are accessing.

Comment: knew it was something stupid.. I'm used to VB.NET..trying to convert this     Public Property dt As DateTime.  Using a vb to c# converter, it excluded 'static' .. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only use a variable in the format `StartForm.dt`, i.e. , `className.variableName` , if the variable is declared `static`, i.e, it is shared by all `instances` of the `class`.

the variable you have declared here `dt`, is an `instance` variable, and is available for each `instance` to use, but not the `class`.

NOTE: in your case, you can probably pass the `current time` as an argument to both of the `forms constructor` , save it in an `instance variable` of that particular form, and use it to calculate loading time.